# How can I play .camrec files made in Camtasia?

Tags: video-player, video-streaming

i have some educational videos which made by [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) Program

do this program save its videos in ***`*.camrec`*** extension

so the problem is that  there is no version for Linux

so how can i play these videos with that extension in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: In the past I have seen a way to extract the encapsulated video from .camrec files. Nevertheless I don't have a sample over here in order to run a test. Do you mind providing such a sample for download from somewhere in order to run the testing and provide a workaround (if possible)? You can always use Camtasia under Windows based Systems in order to create an AVI file from source. Thank you.

Comment: None of the 7-zip answers below worked for me, with the `p7zip -d` command, on e.g. the file stored (as "raw") here: https://github.com/Introduction-to-Autonomous-Robots/Introduction-to-Autonomous-Robots/blob/master/screencasts/rotation_part1.camrec
I got "unknown suffix". After rename to .7z. I get `Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive`
It is identified by `file` as `camrec: Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none of the current (as of Friday, 12th October, 2012) softwares support *.camrec, you might have to convert *.camrec to *.AVI before watching the videos in Ubuntu.

**How to convert *.camrec to *.AVI:**

> 1. Open "Camtasia Studio." Click "Import media." Select on the window the ".Camrec" file you wish to convert to ".AVI." Click "Open."
> 2. Drag the file, which has appeared in the clip bin, onto the time line at the bottom of the screen.
> 3. Click "Produce video as..." on the left-hand side of the window. Select "Custom production settings" and click "Next." Select "AVI video" from the list of formats. Click "Next" four times, which will take you through all of the video settings. Type a "Production name" into the box at the top and select a location for the file to be saved. Click "Finish." Once it is converted, the video will play and be saved to your selected location.

—[How to Convert Camrec to AVI | eHow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_7166465_convert-camrec-avi.html#ixzz291zjrVNw)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: If you do this, make it clear that you are quoting the source, to avoid plagiarizing.

Answer (score 11):

You can use 7-Zip to open .camrec files, it's possible it's just a renamed extension. The video is .AVI inside, however, if you've recorded system audio, it stores it as a separate WAV file, and the Microphone or other selected audio source is encoded into the AVI. I had a great batch process to unpack, remux (to overwrite the microphone with system audio) and encode camrecs to AVI with commandline 7-Zip and virtualdub, but unfortunately lost it in a hard drive crash a few months ago. Have to work on it again... in any case, just knowing 7-Zip can handle camrecs without having to open Camtasia Studio is valuable enough. I know there's a 7-Zip linux port; none for virtualdub but it shouldn't be too hard to find an alternative.

Comment: I can confirm that the camrec I have is a zip type file and I have extracted it using 7zip and see an AVI file in there

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to Camtasia Studio, you can also extract the recorded video from the CAMREC file.

Just rename the file, changing the CAMREC extension to ZIP. Open the new file with the ZIP extension with the free 7-Zip program. You'll find several files inside, including Screen_Stream.avi - this is the actual screen recording file in AVI format. Extract that file.

Answer (score 0):

The above steps did not work for me. I used the procedure described below:

1. Open "Camtasia Studio" --> Click "Import media" --> Select the `.camrec` file you wish to convert to `.AVI` --> Click "Open".
2. Drag the file, which has appeared in the clip bin, onto the time line at the bottom of the screen.
3. Right click on the file in clip bin --> select the property "Extract Camrec Contents" ... it will save the file in .avi format.